# Magento backend new order, new customer - email field missing

Tags: orders, backend

we have th strangest problem. In admin/sales_order_create/index the email field is missing. We actually found this in 2 stores.

The form is loaded here

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Form/Account.php

```
// add system required attributes
foreach ($customerForm->getSystemAttributes() as $attribute) {
    /* @var $attribute Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute */
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired()) {
        $attributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
    }
}
```

It seems that $attribute->getIsRequired() is not true for $attribute->getAttributeCode()=="email"

I have seen this for the 3rd time now in 3 stores.

**Question:** Where and how can the required-ness of the "email" attribute be changed? (so we don't see this problem anymore)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We changed this line to:

```
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired()||$attribute->getAttributeCode()=="email") { // TEMP MODIFICATION
        $attributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute; 
    }
```

But I don't know how the required-ness of the "email" attribute changed. If someone has an answer to that I am very interested

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and solved. You can make Email field require.
Please update below code

```
protected function

addAdditionalFormElementData(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)

{

switch ($element->getId()) {

case 'email':

$element->setRequired(1);

$element->setClass('validate-email');

break;

}

return $this;

}
```

In app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Form/Account.php.